# GWT-GXT Containers and Layouts Overview

Tags: gxt, gwt-ext

Anybody know of a good description of containers/layouts/panels/etc for GXT?  All the tutorials I've seen usually pick one or two and just use them.  Nobody seems to explain the who/what/when/where/how of using various combinations.

Thanx,
~r

PS
Actually I have a slightly complex app (~150 java classes; 8 separate tabs with lots of grids, and lists and tons of RPC calls).  Seems my grids are not displaying a horizontal scroll-bar and I suspect it's because I'm using some container/layout combination that prevents it (not FitLayout  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Best source to know about the container, layouts is GXT samples. They are available if you download GXT. You can also checkout the examples in the GXT site. Here is the [link](http://www.sencha.com/examples/explorer.html)